# Angular 2 custom component inside root component crashing app

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have what seems to be an easy issue that I've been trying to get around when learning Angular 2. Creating a component and then putting that component inside the root component. When I don't add in the other component, the page loads up. When i import in my custom component and add the directive to the root component, the page stays at loading and doesn't go anywhere from there, like its crashing. I can't seem to figure it out.

My custom component (my-c.component.ts):

```
import {component} from 'angular2/core'; 

@component({
    selector: 'my-comp',
    template: `
        <h3>Second component</h3>
    `
    })

export class mycComponent {

}
```

And now here's my "root" component with my custom component inserted. (app.component.ts)

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {mycComponent} from './my-c.component';


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <h1>Angular 2 Boilerplate (o yea)</h1>
        <h2>Now comes the second component</h2>
        <my-comp></my-comp>
    `,
    directives: [mycComponent]

})

export class AppComponent {

}
```

And in my index.html file without all the header stuff for simplicity.
This does not include all the includes for the polyfills and also the system.config to "start" the app, those are all in there.

```
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
```

When i take out the import of my custom component and also remove the directive, I get this:

[image: Working without directive in it]

And this is what happens when I add in the directive [mycComponent] into the root component.

[image: Not working with directive included :(]

Here's a picture of my index.html incase you wanted to see it.

[image: index.html]

This seems like it should be one of the most easiest things to comprehend and work but for some reason I'm stuck here.

Would appreciate any help as to why you think it may not be working :(

File structure >

[image: File structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be the lower case "c" in your second components @Component decorator?

Comment: I spent about 2 hours looking through this and I never even noticed that! I changed the lower case c to C in both the custom @Component and also the import command to import my custom component was a lowercase c. Just needed a 2nd eye at this. Thank you very much for your help!